# How does kernel sharing work in a dual-OS infotainment system?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, posix

I am interested in learning more about the architecture and design of an infotainment system that runs two different operating systems, such as Posix and Android, on the same hardware. How do they share the kernel resources and communicate with each other? What are the benefits and challenges of this approach? Do you have any examples or references of such systems? Thank you for your help.

I read the AUTOSAR documents and learned about the operating system and hardware of the infotainment systems. Posix is the main operating system of the infotainment system, and I need to know how it shares the kernel resources with another operating system, such as Android, that runs concurrently on the same system.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.